# How do I display the text of a html span tag in a capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I am running the following integration test on ruby on rails capybara.

```
test "displays correct date" do
        
   assert page.has_content? @item.begining_date.strftime("%B %d")
end
```

I get false expected truthy. To try and debug this I want to see what is actually being displayed in the page during tests because I get the proper date when I run the website on my local host. I know that the html tag that displays the dates for the items have and id called date1, date2, date3, and so on.

like in the following example.

```
<span id="date1">Fri, June 12</span>
```

I want to display on my console/terminal what is in the span tags with id = "date1", id = "date2",...etc. So that when I run the tests I know what is actually being displayed instead of the expected content.

Comment: Not clear what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: you want the `id` of `item2` to put inside the html `id` field?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your rspec assertion to

```rb
  assert page.has_selector? '#date1', text: 'what you expect the text to be'
```

Then the error message when the test fails will indicate that the selector '#date1' was found but instead of the text you expected, it contains 'some other text'. This way you will know what was actually on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your issue is that you should never use raw `assert` with Capybara methods. If you instead use the assertions provided by Capybara you'll get error messages that give you useful information instead of "expected true got false"

```
assert_content @item.begining_date.strftime("%B %d")
```

will output what the content of the page is if it doesn't match

```
assert_selector '#date1', text: @item.begining_date.strftime("%B %d")
```

will output the contents of the element with id 'date1' if it doesn't match the provided `text` option.

If you're ever writing `assert <any_capybara_provided_predicate>?...` you're doing something wrong.